# Quantified propositions and brackets

Tags: logic

Just wanted to ask if this
$$\exists y\ Q(x,y)\wedge P(x)$$
is equivalent to 
$$\exists y\big(Q(x,y)\wedge P(x)\big)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just wanted to ask if *this* is equivalent to *that*.

Yes, they are equivalent.

If and there exists some $y$ that satisfies $Q(x,y)$, and $P(x)$ is satisfied, then there exists some $y$ that satisfies $Q(x,y)\land P(x)$.

If there exists some $y$ that satisfies $Q(x,y)\land P(x)$, then there exists some $y$ that satisfies $Q(x,y)$, and $P(x)$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a truth table based on the value of $P(x)$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P(x) & \exists yQ(x, y)\land P(x) & \exists y\left(Q(x, y)\land P(x)\right)\\
\hline \text{True} & \exists y Q(x, y) & \exists y \left(Q(x, y)\right)\\
\text{False}&\text{False}&\text{False}
\end{array}
$$
We see that the two expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using formal semantics:

For any interpretation $I$ and variable-assignment $v$, we have:

$I,v \vDash \exists y\ Q(x,y)\land P(x)$ iff (by semantics of $\land$)

$I,v \vDash \exists y\ Q(x,y)$, and $I,v \vDash P(x)$ iff (by semantics of $\exists$)

It is both true that 1) there exists some $d \in D_I$ such that $I,v \vDash Q([v(x)],[d])$, and 2) $I,v \vDash P([v(x)])$ iff (by pure logic)

There exists some $d \in D_I$ such that both $I,v \vDash Q([v(x)],[d])$ and $I,v \vDash P([v(x)])$ iff (by semantics $\land$)

There exists some $d \in D_I$ such that $I,v \vDash Q(x,y)\land P(x)$ iff (semantics $\exists$)

$I,v \vDash \exists y\ (Q(x,y)\land P(x))$

Note: the square brackets in something like $I,v \vDash P([v(x)])$ means that we can extend our language with a new constant $c$, and that we can extend interpretation $I$ into a new interpretation $I'$, which is the same as $I$, but in addition maps the new constant $c$ to the object $v(x)$, such that $I',v \vDash P(c)$. In short: the object $v(x)$ 'satisfies' formula $P(x)$